# How to display current mode IdeaVIM is in?

Tags: statusbar, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

I would like to see which Vim mode I am currently in while using IdeaVIM in PyCharm, or any other JetBrains IDE.

It happens that I select a single character with the mouse (e.g. accidental double-click on a single letter) and the cursor then doesn't distinguish properly between normal mode and visual mode, which makes for awkward situations after hitting a few keys.

Is there a way to display the current mode at all times in the status bar or somewhere else that I have missed?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Put `set showmode` into your ~/.ideavimrc or vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-943.

Comment: `.ideavimrc` was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Issue Vim-943 solves a different problem, I've yet to disable IdeaVIM temporarily. I do like the idea though and have upvoted the issue.